# One word to describe 'living in the moment'?

Tags: single-word-requests

Title says it all - I am looking for a single word to describe 'living in the moment' or 'appreciating the now'.  Something similar to 'Carpe Diem'.

I've used a thesaurus, but only can find multiple word answers.

A simple sample of how I would like to use it:

"Enjoy your life through _________"

Comment: YOLO - one word to sum up living in the moment.

Comment: Its a funny answer, but unfortunately its not an actual word.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to find a verb that means *to live in the moment*. There are single-word nouns that mean that, but they wouldn't be drop-in replacements in your example sentence. I'll note that [YOLO](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/yolo) does have an entry in Lexico (Oxford), even if not in Merriam-Webster yet.

Comment: You are correct about the drop-in - I've adjusted the sample to reflect that.  Regarding YOLO - is it considered a word and not an acronym?

Comment: _Carpe Diem_ sounds like exactly what you want. Why do you want something (else) similar to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Live for the moment
- Live for today
- Live for now
- Live for the here and now

All of these idioms mean roughly the same thing, and I think the single-word you are looking for is *mindfulness*.

"Mindfulness" is defined as "a mental state achieved by focusing one's awareness on the present moment, while calmly acknowledging and accepting one's feelings, thoughts, and bodily sensations, used as a therapeutic technique".

Also note [this recent article](https://www.psychologytoday.com/gb/articles/200811/the-art-now-six-steps-living-in-the-moment) from *Psychology Today* which says "Living in the moment—also called mindfulness—is a state of active, open, intentional attention on the present."

Alternatively, but a little more highbrow, you might consider:

"Epicureanism" - a Greek philosophy from around 307BCE. I'm sure there was a lot more to the philosophy, but today it is most widely known in pop culture for the saying "eat, drink and be merry for tomorrow we may die".

Answer (score 1):

FOCUSED

pay particular attention to.

Comment: This would also be improved by including a cited dictionary definition.